# Adicionar borda sobre uma imagem e texto

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Como faço para sobrepor uma `border` sobre uma imagem e um texto, deixando uma `border` para a imagem como a imagem em anexo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quer uma borda para a div?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor

Comment: cria uma div pai, com o background-image com a imagem que quer de fundo(com o background-attachment: content) ai depois coloca uma div filho com borda e margem, essa div irá ser pai do texto e do botao que tem na imagem

Comment: Se bem entendi, basta apenas criar uma `div` com essas 2 divs dentro certo?

Comment: Adicione código por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de construir essa borda é criando um *pseudo-elemento* no elemento onde está inserido o conteúdo, com posição `absolute` e dimensões em `%` um pouco menor que o `elemento-pai`:

```
.box::after{
   content: '';
   display: block;
   width: 93%;
   height: 93%;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   position: absolute;
   top: 3%; left: 3%;
}
```

**Teste:**

```css
.box{
   display: block; width: 200px; text-align: center;
   position: relative; padding-bottom: 50px; float: left; margin: 0 5px;
}

.box::after{
   content: '';
   display: block;
   width: 93%;
   height: 93%;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   position: absolute;
   top: 3%; left: 3%;
}

.box p{
   display: inline-block; padding: 0 50px;
}

.box img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="box">
   <img src="https://abrilmdemulher.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/receita-bolo-chocolate-com-morango.jpg?quality=90&strip=info&w=620&h=372&crop=1" />
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   <br />
   <button>SAIBA MAIS</button>
</a>

<a href="#" class="box">
   <img src="https://abrilmdemulher.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/receita-bolo-chocolate-com-morango.jpg?quality=90&strip=info&w=620&h=372&crop=1" />
   <br />
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   <br />
   <button>SAIBA MAIS</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @DvD

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção é usar a classe `outline` com `offset` negativo. 
Simplificando o código ficaria assim:

```
.outline {
    outline: red 1px solid;
    outline-offset: -10px;
}

<img class="outline" src="./suaImagem.jpg" alt=" ">
```

[]'s

Comment: O problema é que outline não tem suporte no IE.

Comment: @ÐvÐ vc tem razão, `outline-offset` só no Edge, no IE não funciona.